# [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]... SQLSTATE[42000] error when generating my databases tables with Doctrine

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I just finished creating my entities in Symfony3 using Doctrine. Now, I want to generate table in order to manage it.
For that reason, I firstly ran this command line to create my database :

```
 php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

And it worked great ! Now I want to generate the tables, I just ran this command line :

```
 php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

and I got this error :

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]                                                                                                                              
An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE contribution (id INT 
AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, question_id INT DEFAULT NULL, libelle TEXT NOT  NULL, 
type VARCHAR(2  
55) NOT NULL, nombre_like INT NOT NULL, date_publication DATETIME NOT NULL,   report TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_EA351E15A4D60759 (libelle), INDEX IDX_EA351  
E151E27F6BF (question_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':                                                       
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'libelle' used in key specification without a key length



[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                                                                                
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1170 BLOB/TEXT column  'libelle' used in key specification without a key length

[PDOException]                                                                                                                     
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'libelle' used in key specification without a key length
```

Here is my Commentaire table entity :

```
  class Commentaire
{
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="libelle", type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $libelle;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="depth", type="integer")
 */
protected $depth;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="parent_id", type="integer")
 */
protected $parent_id;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nombre_like", type="integer")
 */
protected $nombreLike;

/**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="date_publication", type="datetimetz", nullable=false)
 */
protected $datePublication;

/**
 * @var bool
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="report", type="boolean")
 */
protected $report;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Contribution", inversedBy="commentaires")
 * @var Contribution
 */
protected $contribution;

/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Enseignant", mappedBy="commentaires")
 */
protected $enseignants;

/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Etudiant", mappedBy="commentaires")
 */
protected $etudiants;


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set libelle
 *
 * @param string $libelle
 *
 * @return Commentaire
 */
public function setLibelle($libelle)
{
    $this->libelle = $libelle;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get libelle
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getLibelle()
{
    return $this->libelle;
}

/**
 * Set depth
 *
 * @param integer $depth
 *
 * @return Commentaire
 */
public function setDepth($depth)
{
    $this->depth = $depth;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get depth
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getDepth()
{
    return $this->depth;
}

/**
 * Set parentId
 *
 * @param integer $parentId
 *
 * @return Commentaire
 */
public function setParentId($parentId)
{
    $this->parent_id = $parentId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get parentId
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getParentId()
{
    return $this->parent_id;
}

/**
 * Set nombreLike
 *
 * @param integer $nombreLike
 *
 * @return Commentaire
 */
public function setNombreLike($nombreLike)
{
    $this->nombreLike = $nombreLike;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get nombreLike
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getNombreLike()
{
    return $this->nombreLike;
}

/**
 * Set datePublication
 *
 * @param \DateTime $datePublication
 *
 * @return Commentaire
 */
public function setDatePublication($datePublication)
{
    $this->datePublication = $datePublication;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get datePublication
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDatePublication()
{
    return $this->datePublication;
}

/**
 * Set report
 *
 * @param boolean $report
 *
 * @return Commentaire
 */
public function setReport($report)
{
    $this->report = $report;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get report
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function getReport()
{
    return $this->report;
}
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->enseignants = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    $this->etudiants = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Set contribution
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Contribution $contribution
 *
 * @return Commentaire
 */
public function setContribution(\AppBundle\Entity\Contribution $contribution = null)
{
    $this->contribution = $contribution;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get contribution
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Contribution
 */
public function getContribution()
{
    return $this->contribution;
}

/**
 * Add enseignant
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Enseignant $enseignant
 *
 * @return Commentaire
 */
public function addEnseignant(\AppBundle\Entity\Enseignant $enseignant)
{
    $this->enseignants[] = $enseignant;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove enseignant
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Enseignant $enseignant
 */
public function removeEnseignant(\AppBundle\Entity\Enseignant $enseignant)
{
    $this->enseignants->removeElement($enseignant);
}

/**
 * Get enseignants
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getEnseignants()
{
    return $this->enseignants;
}

/**
 * Add etudiant
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Etudiant $etudiant
 *
 * @return Commentaire
 */
public function addEtudiant(\AppBundle\Entity\Etudiant $etudiant)
{
    $this->etudiants[] = $etudiant;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove etudiant
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Etudiant $etudiant
 */
public function removeEtudiant(\AppBundle\Entity\Etudiant $etudiant)
{
    $this->etudiants->removeElement($etudiant);
}

/**
 * Get etudiants
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getEtudiants()
{
    return $this->etudiants;
}}
```

libelle seems correct, but I don't know why I got that error. I even changed the type of libelle to string, but the error remains. I think is because doctrine adds index on libelle column (see the query) which is prohibited because the type is TEXT. Any idea how to remove that ? Please help !

Answer (score 0):

The error message says it all:

> BLOB/TEXT column 'libelle' used in key specification without a key length

MySQL documentation on [create index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) statement says (highlighting is mine):

> For string columns, indexes can be created that use only the leading
>   part of column values, using col_name(length) syntax to specify an
>   index prefix length:
>
> • Prefixes can be specified for CHAR, VARCHAR, BINARY, and VARBINARY
>   column indexes.
>
> • **Prefixes must be specified for BLOB and TEXT column indexes.**
>
> • Prefix limits are measured in bytes, whereas the prefix length in
>   CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, and CREATE INDEX statements is interpreted
>   as number of characters for nonbinary string types (CHAR, VARCHAR,
>   TEXT) and number of bytes for binary string types (BINARY, VARBINARY,
>   BLOB). Take this into account when specifying a prefix length for a
>   nonbinary string column that uses a multibyte character set.
>
> • For spatial columns, prefix values cannot be given, as described
>   later in this section.
>
> The statement shown here creates an index using the first 10
>   characters of the name column (assuming that name has a nonbinary
>   string type):
>
> ```
> CREATE INDEX part_of_name ON customer (name(10));
> ```

This means that you **must** use a prefix on the index created for the `libelle` field. Doctrine added a unique restriction on the `libelle` field., remove this restriction if not needed, then there will not be any need to create the index anyway.

Alternative is to change the data type in the database to varchar.

Comment: How to remove that restriction please ?

Comment: You have to check your code because the above code excerpt does not contain any such restriction. Therefore I cannot be more specific.